# Original filename in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, nodes

Is it possible to get original filename from a file with an absolute path in node?

For instance, in node I can get the name and base url with `path.basename` and more detailed info with `fs.stats`, which will result in:

```
Stats {
  dev: 2114,
  ino: 48064969,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 85,
  gid: 100,
  rdev: 0,
  size: 527,
  blksize: 4096,
  blocks: 8,
  atimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  mtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  ctimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  birthtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  atime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  mtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  ctime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  birthtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT }
```

None of these method however will give me the original name of the file, which is useful for comparing 2 files to each other. For instance, if I download a file called `file.exe` from some website and then download the same file again, the new file will be called `file (1).exe` and has therefore not the same name as original.

Because of this I can't compare the filenames to each other.

Anyone know a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, if I download a file called `file.exe` from some website and then download the same file again, the new file will be called `file (1).exe` and has therefore not the same name as original.

In the general case, the name of the file is not stored in the file data anywhere, so if you've downloaded the file as `file (1).exe`, you have no way of knowing that it was called `file.exe` at some point in the past.

In the specific case of an .exe file, *some* name may or may not be somewhere in the file's contents, but it's not necessarily the name it most recently had before you renamed it.

Comment: This is the answer. The name of a file is not stored inside the file itself, it is stored in the filesystem. If you want to compare two files, use its content (or a hash of the content).

Comment: So in order to get the original name I need to read the filesystem? Is it possible to achieve want I want from reading in the filesystem?

Comment: @Aborgh - No, it isn't, because the name in the filesystem is `file (1).exe`. You cannot do what you've said you want to do, at all, in the general case. The information just isn't there once you've saved the file as `file (1).exe`.

Comment: This might be a stupid follow up question but using mdls on macOS I can get alot more info on a file. Is it possible to get metadata from a file in both windows and POSIX systems?

Comment: @Aborgh - Yes, sometimes, depending on the file. In Windows (and many \*nix file managers) you can right-click a file and see properties for it. Some file types won't have much to show; others (like .Net executables) will have quite a lot.

Comment: So is it possible to that information in node or JavaScript?

Comment: @Aborgh - Of course it is -- the information is accessible, and Node.js lets you write just about any arbitrary program. I haven't done it and have no specific pointers, but if the info is there, of course you can access it from a general-purpose programming environment.